# spike in accuracy at k =1 using caret in R

Tags: r, r-caret, knn, caret

I'm using a complete version of the wine quality dataset [here](http://www3.dsi.uminho.pt/pcortez/wine/) to try and use knn to classify wine into categories of quality using caret in R. I've appended the "white" and "red" data together and added a colour variable.
I'm running into a strange issue where the k-value seems to be spike for k=1, and so training with caret constantly returns models that are using this value. This is despite the fact that other examples on the internet using this or a very similar dataset seem to get optimal k's in the 14-20 range.

Here's my code:

```
# partition quality ratings into groups
data2 = data %>%
  mutate(quality2 = case_when(quality %in% c(3,4,5) ~ "Low",
                              quality %in% c(6) ~ "Med",
                              quality %in% c(7,8,9) ~ "High"
                              )) %>%
  select(-c(quality, colour))

# partition dataset
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data2$quality2, p = .75, 
                                  list = FALSE)
datTrain <- data2[ trainIndex, ]
datTest  <- data2[-trainIndex,]

# train model

train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                              number = 10)

fit_knn <- train(quality2~ .,
             method     = "knn",
             tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:20),
             trControl  = train.control,
             preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
             metric = "Accuracy",
             data = datTrain)
fit_knn
```

This seems to happen with or without the quality partitioning, and also happens when I try to use caret's knn to predict colour of the wine as opposed to quality

[this is my plot of accuracy for the quality classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU6eI.png)

The strangest part is it seems that this behaviour only cropped up after running the code multiple times. I'm not sure what changed, but now no matter what I do (restart R, update caret, etc.) it seems stuck on this "optimal" value for k.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce your results. Please do `set.seed` to ensure reproducibility.

The signal in the data is very low.
Points with similar features do not cluster well by the `quality2` class.
k=1 is always the best classifier on the training dataset but (probably) always the worst when it comes to do predictions on new datasets.
I'd suggest to enforce a higher `k` to apply the concept of regularization.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

set.seed(1337)

data <- tibble(
  colour = c("red", "white"),
  file = c("winequality/winequality-red.csv", "winequality/winequality-white.csv")
) %>%
  transmute(
    colour,
    data = file %>% map(~ .x %>% read_delim(delim = ";"))
  ) %>%
  unnest(data)



## partition quality ratings into groups
data2 = data %>%
  mutate(quality2 = case_when(quality %in% c(3,4,5) ~ "Low",
                              quality %in% c(6) ~ "Med",
                              quality %in% c(7,8,9) ~ "High"
  )) %>%
  select(-c(quality, colour))

# partition dataset
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data2$quality2, p = .75, 
                                  list = FALSE)
datTrain <- data2[ trainIndex, ]
datTest  <- data2[-trainIndex,]

train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                              number = 10)

fit_knn <- train(quality2~ .,
                 method     = "knn",
                 tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:20),
                 trControl  = train.control,
                 preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                 metric = "Accuracy",
                 data = datTrain)
fit_knn


data2 %>%
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  prcomp() %>%
  pluck("x") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  bind_cols(data2) %>%
  qplot(PC1, PC2, color = quality2, data = .)
```

Two dimensions are sufficient for plotting:

[image]

There is no strong signal in the data:

[image]

Comment: can you reproduce the results I had above with the same dataset?

Comment: @MirandaGreen yes, I revised my answer.